# Why does my subclass keep saying it's not initialized?

Tags: ruby, class, subclass

Why do I keep getting a NameError saying that `Cherry` is an uninitialized constant when I call `Cherry.new`? I'm not yet versed in creating subclasses yet.

```
class Red
  def initialize(options = {})
    @options = options
  end

  def instance_method_a
    return @options[:a] if @options.has_key?(:a)
    if @options.has_key?(:b)
      #mathy code
    end
  end

  def instance_method_b
    return @options[:b] if @options.has_key?(:b)
    if @options.has_key?(:a)
      #mathy code
    end
  end

  class Cherry < Red
    def initialize(var)
      self.new(:a => var)
    end
  end

  class Vermillion < Red
    def initialize(var)
      self.new(:b => var)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm sure that `Vermillion` is going to be just as uninitialized. I need to be able to assign variables to those subclasses to run them through the instance method. How can I get these to work?

Comment: `Subclass A` is not valid class name, you can't have spaces in class names or any variable/constant names.

Comment: I edited it. I was changing the names and I just messed that part up. My other program just has it as a capitalized one word.

Comment: Please use some other name than `Class` as Ruby already has a `Class` class of which all classes are object of.  If still face an issue, post an updated question.

Comment: I think I should just rewrite the question, hold on. The actual question has me devising a class Temperature, but I don't want t post that solution online so I just changed the names of everything. The subclasses are Celsius and Fahrenheit.

Comment: You shouldn't nest a class inside another class. You can do it, but there's almost never a good reason to. Also, calling `self.new` inside `initialize` will fail because `new` is a class method, but inside `initialize` `self` is an instance, not the class. Use `super`. If you're getting an error, edit your question to include the exact error message and stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `super` with arguments to invoke the base class's `initialize` method.

```
  class Cherry < Red
    def initialize(var)
      super(:a => var)
    end
  end
```

Additionally, your subclasses are namespaced inside the main class. You need to invoke them with the namespace.

`Red::Cherry.new(something: "here")`

Comment: Tried that. :/ `super(:a => var)` threw up a bunch of errors and `super(a: => var)` gives me the uninitialized constant NameError

Comment: So wait, if I try to initialize the subclasses outside of the main class, will that work?

Comment: @SiouxsieAsylum Yes, then you can call it without namespacing

Comment: GOT IT!! Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I keep getting a `NameError` saying that `Subclass_A` is an uninitialized constant?

Simple: there is no `Subclass_A` in your code.